# Why does this not contradict 'Solutions of $\dot{x} = f(x)$ cannot intersect"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Say we have $\dot{x} = cos(x^2)$ and $x(0) = 1$, and also $\dot{y} = cos(y^2)$ and $y(0) = 0.5$

Then by the MVT we know that $0.5 < \frac{y(1)-y(0)}{1 - 0} < 1$, which implies that $y(0) = 0.5 < x(0) = 1< y(1)$.

How does this not contradict that solutions of an autonomous ODE, $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuously differentiable, cannot cross?

I think this may be down to a misunderstanding in general of what the above theorem means. I thought it meant that solutions of the same ODE, for different initial conditions, cannot physically cross, even if this happens at different times, but in the above we seem to have different initial conditions, and a solution physically crossing the path of another solution. Is it something to do with the solutions being 1 dimensional?

Answer (score 3):

The solutions $x$ and $y$ of an autonomous ODE (or system) DO NOT CROSS means that:

Either $\big\{\big(t,x(t)\big):t\in I\big\}=\big\{\big(t,y(t)\big):t\in I\big\}$
or $\big\{\big(t,x(t)\big):t\in I\big\}\cap\big\{\big(t,y(t)\big):t\in I\big\}=\varnothing$.

In what you observe, there exists a $t_0\in(0,1)$, such that
$$
y(t_0)=x(0).
$$

The two solutions cross if there exists a $t_0$, such that $x(t_0)=y(t_0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this a better (colloquial) definition: they either do not physically cross at all (i.e. if you were to draw their phase portrait there would be no physical intersection of lines), OR if they cross they 'stick together'?